# Why use an attribute selector to match classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have found [an example](http://www.zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates) of responsive email templates where there are such CSS selectors such as the following:

```
a[class="btn"]
```

Why is this syntax used if it could be replaced with the simpler:

```
a.btn
```

Does it have any impact on mobile browsers or anything else? Are there email clients that require this usage?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The `[]` syntax is an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).

```
a[class="btn"]
```

This will select any `<a>` tag with `class="btn"`. However, it will *not* select `<a>` which has `class="btn btn_red"`, for example (whereas [`a.btn`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) would). It only *exactly matches* that attribute.

You may want to read [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/). It's invaluable to any up-and-coming web developer.

Comment: but it has nothing to do responsiveness, it's pure CSS syntax, right?

Comment: I also came across the same tutorial (http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/coding/) - it seems odd that they would use this technique in a tutorial. Tutorials should make things as clear as possible for people starting out. Especially when the common `.btn` selector would suffice. Am i missing somthing? Is there any benefit to this? Greater specificity I am guessing?

Comment: isn't there a new way to select all the class names using jQuery and brackets to get at all classes with the same prefix?  Something like $(this).css("[class~='btn_']", "red");  The syntax might be wrong, but do you know what the correct syntax is?

Comment: @whyoz I think you're looking for `[class^='btn_']`.

Comment: It would be great if you updated your answer to show the other types of attribute selectors as well.  Searching for "css selector square brackets" brings up this question in a search, and it is difficult to search for the other variations ("css selector square brackets star").

Comment: I fixed the title so the question should no longer come up in those searches. A primer on attribute selectors doesn't really belong here.

Comment: No one notices this doesn't answer the question? I know what the selector *does*, but I'm trying to figure out *why* it's being used in emails. I would love to strip it out of our projects, but I know there's some archaic browser out there that needs it. It would be great to know which one it is so I can evaluate the necessity.

Answer (score 1):

> Why use an attribute selector to match classes?

**The obvious use case for attribute selector: Specific matches**

Exact match `=`, containing/substring `*=`, prefix `^=`, suffix `$=`, [etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

**Yahoo Mail Hack**

- You want to support beta versions of Yahoo Mail
- You have media queries

Normally apps made before media queries just ignore the whole block - not beta yahoo mail, which just applies all the styles ignoring the media query. It doesn't support attribute selectors though...

For this case you can use attribute selectors to select a class within a media query so that the media query works on most email clients but doesn't trigger media query styles on beta versions of yahoo mail.

[read more here](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/stop_yahoo_mail_from_rendering_your_media_queries/)

Caniemail data on the [attribute-selector](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-selector-attribute/) having much less support than the [class selector](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-selector-class/).

Comment: Older versions of Yahoo Mail were the reason attribute selectors were used, but apparently that is no longer required, which I will try to verify. https://litmus.com/community/discussions/262-classname-vs-img-class-classname-vs-img-class-classname

Comment: @BBaysinger OH This is making a lot more sense now, I am going to update the answer, thank you!

Comment: @BBaysinger I have updated the answer to include yahoo mail

Comment: It doesn't seem like your statement on Yahoo Mail is consistent with the explanation in the link I provided.

Comment: @BBaysinger Can you be more specific? I linked an article that seemed to go into more detail than yours, reading yours again and don't know what's inconsistent

Comment: Oh, nm. It looks like I read it wrong.