# CSS: [hidden] {display:none}

Tags: html, css

Could someone please let me know what the bracket means around the word `hidden` in the following CSS code? Does it look for the classes in the `html` code that are named `hidden` to set their display property to `none`? If so, aren't the brackets redundant?

```
[hidden] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It means it's an attribute (e.g. `<span hidden></span>`, `<input hidden />`, etc.)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604182/css-square-brackets-selector-for-classes).

Comment: If that is all the code that there is, then it's invalid. There should be an element, class, or ID name preceding the brackets at the very least.

Comment: @TylerH It's not invalid. `[hidden]` is equivalent to `*[hidden]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Attribute selectors
```

CSS 2.1 allows authors to specify rules that match elements which have certain attributes defined in the source document.

`Matching attributes and attribute values`

Attribute selectors may match in four ways:

1. `[att]` Match when the element sets the "att" attribute, whatever the
   value of the attribute.
2. `[att=val]` Match when the element's "att" attribute value is exactly
   "val".
3. `[att~=val]` Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
   is a white space-separated list of words, one of which is exactly
   "val". If "val" contains white space, it will never represent
   anything (since the words are separated by spaces). If "val" is the
   empty string, it will never represent anything either.
4. `[att|=val]` Represents an element with the att attribute, its value
   either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately
   followed by "-" (U+002D). This is primarily intended to allow
   language subcode matches (e.g., the hreflang attribute on the a
   element in HTML) as described in BCP 47 ([BCP47]) or its successor.
   For lang (or xml:lang) language subcode matching, please see the
   :lang pseudo-class. Attribute values must be identifiers or strings.
   The case-sensitivity of attribute names and values in selectors
   depends on the document language.

> For example, the following attribute selector matches all H1 elements
>   that specify the "title" attribute, whatever its value:

```
h1[title] { color: blue; }
```

In the following example, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "class" attribute has exactly the value "example":

```
span[class=example] { color: blue; }
```

Multiple attribute selectors can be used to refer to several attributes of an element, or even several times to the same attribute.

Here, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "hello" attribute has exactly the value "Cleveland" and whose "goodbye" attribute has exactly the value "Columbus":

```
span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"] { color: blue; }
```

The following selectors illustrate the differences between "=" and "~=". The first selector will match, for example, the value "copyright copyleft copyeditor" for the "rel" attribute. The second selector will only match when the "href" attribute has the value "http://www.w3.org/".

```
a[rel~="copyright"]
a[href="http://www.w3.org/"]
```