# What is wrong with multiple classes to elements for media query selectors? Or what is going on here?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for horus to figure out a problem with a webpage I made and I've narrowed down it down to being something to do with multiple classes and I've made a fiddle for proof.

**HTML:**

```
<p class="bg-yellow-on-mobile">
  Should have a yellow background on mobile
</p>
<p class="bg-yellow-on-mobile talign-right-on-mobile">
  Should have a yellow background and text aligned right on mobile
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width:767px){
  [class="bg-yellow-on-mobile"] { background: yellow; }
  [class="talign-right-on-mobile"] { text-align: right; }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4w9L16g3/

You'll see that the mobile styles are not applied to the second `<p>` tag, the one with two classes. Is the reason ***because*** it has multiple classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS square brackets selector for classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604182/css-square-brackets-selector-for-classes)

Answer (score 5):

you need to use the **`*`** caractere to select the classname, that it is exactly whats in the attribute or part of it

> https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-selectors-20010126/#attribute-selectors
>
> 6.3.2 Substring matching attribute selectors
>
> Three different attribute selectors are also available for pattern representation into the value of an attribute :
>
> [att^="val"]
>
> Represents the att attribute, its value beginning exactly with the prefix "val"
>
> [att$=ident]
>
> Represents the att attribute, its value ending exactly with the suffix "ident"
>
> [att*="val"]
>
> Represents the att attribute, its value containing at least once the substring "val"

```css
@media (max-width:767px){
  [class*="bg-yellow-on-mobile"] { background: yellow; }
  [class*="talign-right-on-mobile"] { text-align: right; }
}
```

```html
<p class="bg-yellow-on-mobile">
  Should have a yellow background on mobile
</p>
<p class="bg-yellow-on-mobile talign-right-on-mobile">
  Should have a yellow background and text aligned right on mobile
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are using looks odd. This works:

```
@media (max-width:767px){
  .bg-yellow-on-mobile { background: yellow; }
  .talign-right-on-mobile { text-align: right; }
}
```

Comment: This may be relevant to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604182/css-square-brackets-selector-for-classes?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

That is a strict equals for the class attribute. Just use `.classname`

Comment: FYI, I have to use this because I'm writing an HTML email and many email clients don't respect the `.` operator. But thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @SubparWebDev - Are you sure the `.` selector is supported by *less* clients than `[class=""]`? [This list here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and this [one here](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/) seem to support the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second rule is not being applied is that you are using the Attribute Selector with the `[att=val]` syntax. According to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), this will match elements when *'the element's "att" attribute value is **exactly** "val".'*

Because your second `<p>` has **multiple** classes, this doesn't count as an exact match and the `text-align: right` style isn't applied.

If your targeted email clients don't support `.classname`, the best approach is to use the `[att~=val]` syntax, i.e `[class~="talign-right-on-mobile"]`. This matches elements *'with the att attribute whose value is a white space-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val"'*, and so it picks up the second `<p>`. Altogether now:

```css
@media (max-width:767px){
    [class~="bg-yellow-on-mobile"] { background: yellow; }
    [class~="talign-right-on-mobile"] { text-align: right; }
}
```

```html
<p class="bg-yellow-on-mobile">
  Should have a yellow background on mobile
</p>
<p class="bg-yellow-on-mobile talign-right-on-mobile">
  Should have a yellow background and text aligned right on mobile
</p>
```