# CSS with '[class]' as part of the selector. The literal string 'class' in brackets

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-email

I'm looking at CSS with this kind of rule in it:

```
table[class].outer{width:600px;}
```

I've never seen this type of selector before and it's almost impossible to search for, even with Google's "verbatim" setting.

Can anyone explain what's going on here? Is it some kind of hack? Is it just a broken CSS3 selector?

In case there's any confusion, not `[class="something"]`, or `[class^="something']` or anything where the string `class` is followed by further code to match the  *content* of the attribute. Literally just open-bracket, c, l, a, s, s, close bracket. This is what I meant by a broken CSS3 selector. A selector for "has a class attribute" with no requirement to match any *particular* attribute.

It might be related to email rendering. The rule doesn't seem to be applied in any normal browser.

Comment: It's an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). It's not doing anything in this case except make the selector more specific.

Comment: Maybe this shouldn't be marked as duplicate? **The `[class]` selector's implications have changed since [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604182/css-square-brackets-selector-for-classes).** Until early 2015, using the bracket selector was the only way to get Yahoo! Mail to recognize the CSS rules. In March 2015, Yahoo! Mail was updated to no longer require bracket selectors. They still work fine, but a single `.classname` works in Yahoo! Mail too.

Comment: I don't necessarily object to this being classed as a duplicate but I do want to make sure the specific code is being understood. It's not `[class=something]` it is literally `[class]`, just the word in the brackets. As a selector it would target any element which had any class attribute of any kind.

Comment: Your question was misunderstood. The duplicate does not apply. I reopened your question.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute selector `[class]` matches any element that has a class attribute. It works exactly the same as you would expect an attribute selector matching by any other attribute, not just class.

There is nothing broken about such a selector *per se*; it is valid CSS. Even if it was necessary for getting CSS in emails working in Yahoo! Mail once upon a time, it isn't anymore. There is nothing wrong with wanting to match only elements that have a class attribute.

What *is* strange, though, is having a `[class]` attribute selector *together with a class selector* in the same compound selector. In HTML, the class selector implies that the element has a class attribute, which makes the attribute selector completely superfluous. The only purpose such a selector could serve, from what I can tell, is increasing specificity. But you can also do that by duplicating the class selector (i.e. `table.outer.outer`) since an attribute selector and a class selector are equally specific. Maybe the author didn't realize that, or they thought duplicating class selectors looked sillier than having a `[class]` attribute selector.

Or maybe it was just a mistake and we will never know.

Answer (score 0):

[class] selector simply means if it has a class for example

```css
div[class] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">somthing</div>

<div>something else</div>

<div class="b">blah blah</div>
```

as you can see first and third div gets the style but the second one doesn't, so in your case in wouldn't do much because if a table's class is .outer then it obviously has a class