# what does this mean? *[class="hide"] in css

Tags: css

What is going on here with this css? 
The * and [] are confusing me, I haven't seen it before.

I realise it is to hide but does it mean if I create an element with class="hide" it will hide it?

I can't find anything online to explain it

```
*[class="hide"] {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: .hide{display:none !important;}

Answer (score 4):

The `*` is the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) that matches a single element of any type. When combined with other selectors, the asterisk can usually be omitted. In your case, you could also just write `[class="hide"]`.

The square brackets `[]` indicate an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) which is used to match elements that have a certain attribute and value combination. In your case `class="hide"` is a match by an exact attribute value. So you are looking for elements that have an attribute `class` which value is *exactly* `hide`.

Usually, people will match `class` attributes using the [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) indicated by a leading dot. So `.hide` would be a mostly equivalent selector to yours.

There is a differences between `.hide` and `[class="hide"]` though: `[class="hide"]` will only match when `hide` is the *only* class of the element. So an element `<div class="warning hide">…</div>` will be matched by `.hide` but not `[class="hide"]`:

```css
.foo {
  color: teal;
}
[class="foo"] {
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Class and attribute selectors will match here</div>
<div class="foo bar">Only the class selector will match here</div>
```

In your case, I’m not sure if that’s such a good idea since a `hide` class is usually used to temporarily hide elements. So it’s just a class you can add to elements to make it disappear and remove it again to get it back. By having a selector that matches on attribute equality, you are essentially preventing yourself from this toggle-ability, as you will have to actively replace all existing class names.

Answer (score 2):

**1.**  `*[class="red"]` selects all elements with the class name exactly *red*. It is same as calling `[class="red"]` ie. the `*` is redundant.

**2.**   `[class*="red"]` selects all elements with the class names containing the string *red* in it.

```css
*[class="red"] {
  color: red
}

[class*='blue'] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">Test 1</div>
<div class="demo-blue-1">Test 2</div>
<div class="demo-blue-2">Test 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a wild card selector and applies to all elements, e.g. `div>*` applies to any element that is directly under a `div`.

The brackets indicate attributes of the elements to match, so this line applies to any element that has a `class` attribute with value `hide`, though I think the logical thing would have been to just define the class `.hide` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

This question may be duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604182/square-brackets-selector-for-classes)

`*[class="hide"]` will select anything with `class="hide"`