# Brackets square html css

Tags: html, css

I can see so many old/new website using it on CSS file.

How important is this?

```
input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=password] {...}
```

If I don't used it on my CSS file would it effect during browser rendering my html page? Should we go without it?

Comment: ok im waiting.. keep writing guys

Comment: _"If I don't used it on my CSS file would it effect during browser rendering my html page?"_ Um, what? This is just [attribute selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). You use it when you need to.

Comment: @j08691 thanks! ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brackets are called "attribute selectors" and don't have any effect on the css or html itself, but are used to select elements with more specificity than class names or id's. In my mind, I associate them with a `regex` to help remember what they do. While you may not *need* them, they can be super useful! When using bootstrap, I often use `[class*="col-"]` to select all classes that start with `col-` (i.e. `col-xs-12` or `col-md-3`) so that I can change the default styles of bootstrap's grid in certain situations. Here's a similar question that may help! [Why use an attribute selector to match classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604182/why-use-an-attribute-selector-to-match-classes)

Comment: Also, here's a little more information on all the different types of CSS selectors that you can use while working on styles: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048 Good luck!

Comment: Ty! can I have your email address?

Answer (score 1):

It is used for styling different types of inputs( email, text, password etc. ). If you don't need to style various inputs with various styles, just skip it.